# How to build a script to backup all databases in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, scripting, backup

We need to backup 40 databases inside a SQL Server instance.  We backup each database with the following script:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [dbname1] TO  DISK = N'J:\SQLBACKUPS\dbname1.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'dbname1-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'dbname1' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'dbname1' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''dbname1'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'J:\SQLBACKUPS\dbname1.bak' WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
GO
```

We will like to add to the script the functionality of taking each database and replacing it in the above script. Basically a script that will create and verify each database backup from an engine.

I am looking for something like this:

```
For each database in database-list
    sp_backup(database) // this is the call to the script above.
End For
```

any ideas?

Comment: ... and restores; how do you restore with a script?

Answer (score 2):

Use [SqlBackupAndFTP](http://SqlBackupAndFTP.com). Select "Backup all non-system databases"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check the [sp_MSForEachDB](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=410) stored procedure.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'EXEC sp_backup ?'
```

Where the ? mark stands for the current database on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You said "verify" too... This would require a 2nd statement per database ([RESTORE VERIFYONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902(SQL.90).aspx), as well the other answers offered.

I'd investigate using [maintenance plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658(SQL.90).aspx) to include index maintenance too...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'BACKUP ' + Name + ' To Disk=''c:\' + Name + '.bak'';'
    FROM sys.sysdatabases

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Backup Master](http://www.sqlbackupmaster.com) has the ability to back up all databases on a given server instance and then send the backups to Dropbox, FTP, Amazon S3, Google Drive, or local/network folder.